# Difference behavior between a python global variable and a global list?

Tags: python, global-variables

I am confused with the python's design of global variables, it seems quite different for a normal global variable and a global list, consider the following code:

```
global_list = []
global_var = 0


def foo():
    for i in range(10):
        global global_var  # without this, error occurs
        global_var += 1
        global global_list  # without this, fine!
        global_list.append(i)


foo()
print(global_list)
print(global_var)
```

The code is quite self-explained, I would like to know why this is the case, what is the logic behind that. Besides, I've also tested a dictionary, it behaves like a list. What about other stuff, such as a class instance or something...

Comment: The *type* of the object is irrelevant. The semantics are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Programming FAQs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

When you write:

```
global_var += 1
```

You are *assigning* a value to the name `global_var` after you have already referenced the global version The `+=` construct needs to read the global then reassign to it — it's equivalent to:

```
global_var = global_var + 1
^            ^
|            |--global reference
|- local assignment
```

According to the above rule, this would make it a local variable unless declared global but you've already referenced the global.

When you write:

```
global_list.append(i)
```

You are not assigning a new value to the name `global_list`. `global_list` still points to the same array, the same thing happens with a dictionary. You would need to declare `global global_list` if you tried to reassign with something like:

```
global_list = global_list + [i]
```

Comment: what about a user declared instance.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the value is @喵喵是我的猫猫. What matters is whether or not you are reassigning the name (i.e. using `=`). If you can alter a user instance in-place without reassigning the name binding you don't need the global. Since things like numbers are immutable, you can't really change them without a reassignment.

Comment: In your answer, `According to the above rule, this would make it a local variable unless declared global but you've already referenced the global.`, if I don't declare it as global, this statement would be a wrong one, instead of making it a local variable.

Comment: If you don't declare it as global and you write `global_var = global_var + 1` You are assigning a local variable with `global_var =`, but trying to read a global with `global_var + 1`. Python evaluates the right hand side first and finds the global variable, but then it's not clear what to do in the assignment on the left-hand side.

Comment: Even if I write `global_var = global_var + 1 `, the code is still a wrong one in my case(python 3.64): `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'global_var' referenced before assignment
`